# Clear slash commands competely

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How can I clear slash commands in both guilds and application.commands? I accidentally duplicated them so I'm trying to clear them.

I have tried to use client.application.commands.set([]) but nothing happened.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the [Documentation](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/deleting-commands.html#deleting-specific-commands) says

> To delete all commands in the respective scope (one guild, all global
> commands) you can pass an empty array when setting commands.
> An example code

```
const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(token);

// ...

// for guild-based commands
rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), { body: [] })
    .then(() => console.log('Successfully deleted all guild commands.'))
    .catch(console.error);

// for global commands
rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(clientId), { body: [] })
    .then(() => console.log('Successfully deleted all application commands.'))
    .catch(console.error);
```

Just run the script with node and it will delete all your slash commands (I usually need to reload discord aswell)

Hope this helps

Comment: Doesn't work, just gives me a code 50053 error. I've used this instead:

client.application.commands.set([]);
    client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
      guild.commands.set([]);
    });

Comment: Can you post the error?